# Максимальные элементы матрицы вдоль побочной диагонали

Tags: c++, сортировка, матрицы

В самой матрице нужно найти N(квадратная матрица имеет размерность nxn) максимальных элементов матрицы и расположить их на побочной диагонали по уменьшению элементов(сорт.выбором), у меня получилось реализовать только в виде поиска макс. эл. по строке и вывода их по побочной диагонали.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
        cout<<"Введите размерность квадратной матрици"<<endl;
        cin>>n;
        cout<<endl;
    int array[n][n];

srand(time(NULL));

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)

    {
        array[i][j] = 1 + rand() % 100-40;
    }
}   
cout<<"Неотсортированная матрица"<<endl;
int row=n;
int col=n;
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
     {
            cout << array[i][j] << "  ";
     }
     cout<<endl;
}
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Матрица с максимальными элемента на побочной диагонали"<<endl;
int iMax,tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        iMax = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
            if (array[i][iMax] < array[i][j])
                iMax = j;

        if (iMax != n - 1 - i)
        {
            tmp = array[i][n - 1 - i];
            array[i][n - 1 - i] = array[i][iMax];
            array[i][iMax] = tmp;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout<<array[i][j]<<"  ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

bool cmp(pair<int, pair<int, int>> a, pair<int, pair<int, int>> b)
{
    return a.first > b.first;
}

int main()
    int n;
    cout << "Matrix size:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;

    srand(time(NULL));
    pair<int, pair<int, int>> arr[n * n];
    int matrix[n][n], free = 0;

    cout << "Generated matrix: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            arr[free] = {matrix[i][j], {i, j}};
            ++free;
            cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    sort(arr, arr + n * n, cmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        swap(matrix[i][n - i -1], matrix[arr[i].second.first][arr[i].second.second]);
    }

    cout << "Sorted matrix:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: да, работает отлично, только мне не понятны 2 момента  bool cmp(pair<int, pair<int, int>> a, pair<int, pair<int, int>> b)
{
    return a.first > b.first;
} и `swap(matrix[i][n - i -1], matrix[arr[i].second.first][arr[i].second.second]);` первое как я понимаю - поиск максимального элемента, а второе?

Comment: И возможно ли их реализовать немного проще?

Comment: 1 - это компоратор для сортировки и он действительно выбирает максимальный, второй  - обмен значений

Comment: эквивалентно вашему коду tmp = array[i][n - 1 - i];
            array[i][n - 1 - i] = array[i][iMax];
            array[i][iMax] = tmp;

Comment: вот есть еще пару вопросов 1) `arr[free] = {matrix[i][j], {i, j}};
            ++free;` free это счетчик,но чего? 2) `pair<int, pair<int, int>> arr[n * n];` у нас же есть matrix или это нужно только для компоратора?  3) почему мы пишем именно так `matrix[arr[i].second.first][arr[i].second.second]` и при этом компилятор не ругается на second ?

Comment: 1) arr - массив соодержащий пару из элемента матрицы и его исходной позиции. free - показывает лишь текущую позицию, в целом эквивалентно i * n + j. 2) пояснил. 3) а почему он должен ругаться? arr[i].second.first - хранит строку, arr[i].second.second - хранит столбец